# Индикатив vs. сослагательное наклонение

Tags: сослагательное-наклонение

Не уверена, разрешено ли это в рамках этого сайта, но хотелось бы воспользоваться широкой аудиторией и провести мини-опрос.

Здесь есть только одна русская девочка, которая "только может говорить, но не может объяснить почему".

Уважаемые носители языка,

какую версию Вы предпочли бы?

> a) Если бы завтра была хорошая погода, мы бы поехали на дачу.
>
> b) Если завтра будет хорошая погода, мы поедем на дачу.

Эта русская девочка сказала немедленно (b) и не задумалась долго. Если большинство из Вас тоже согласится с (b), тогда какой может быть контекст, когда русский человек предпочел бы версию (а)?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Не думаю, что нужен опрос (голосование). Ваш вопрос ничем не отличается от других вопросов. Существует **объективный** ответ на него.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что он такой же дурацкий как мои другие вопросы? =) наверно здесь меня ненавидят уже...

Comment: Раз отвечают - значит все в порядке!

Comment: Ваши вопросы, обращенные к носителям языка,  заставляют их задуматься над теми  синтаксическими конструкциями, которыми они обычно пользуются  интуитивно. А это очень  полезное занятие, поэтому мы с удовольствием   стараемся  по возможности ответить вам.

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке употребление сослагательного в первом примере некорректно, поскольку в русском языке сослагательное наклонение не имеет временного противопоставления: вчера, сегодня, завтра пошел бы дождь.

Вот что говорится в Г-80.

Грамматическим значением формы сослагат. накл. является значение возможности в **неопределенном временном плане.**

Однако в **Русской корпусной грамматике** говорится, что в подобных примерах   описываемая ситуация относятся скорее к фантастической, чем к гипотетической.

> 4.2 Употребление сослагательного наклонения в условных конструкциях
>
> 4.2.1 Семантика сослагательного наклонения в условных конструкциях

Сослагательное наклонение встречается в условных конструкциях, обозначающих ситуации, которые не были реализованы и не будут реализованы (наиболее частый случай) или являются маловероятными **(такие примеры встречаются редко).**

Ситуации первого типа относятся к прошлому или к настоящему. Их принято назвать контрфактивными [Подлесская 1999: 256][2]:

> (78) Ты ведь даже в ресторан тогда бы не поехал, если бы я за тебя не заплатил. [А. Геласимов. Ты можешь (2001)]
>
> (79) Если бы такую записку прислала Света Кириллова или, например, Соня Ганчук, Глебов разволновался бы гораздо сильнее. [Ю. Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)]
>
> (80) Если бы она могла сейчас видеть, как я, не отрываясь, коряво узорю эту бумагу, то сказала бы что-то вроде: «Когда будешь делать конец?» [М. Палей. Поминовение (1987)]

**Ситуации второго типа относятся к будущему. Их называют гипотетическими [Подлесская 1999: 256]:**

(81) Если бы парламентские выборы состоялись завтра, то в них смогла бы принять участие 41 политическая партия. [«Независимая газета» (2003)]

**Условные конструкции с сослагательным наклонением и референцией к будущему встречаются крайне редко.** В выборке **из 518 примеров условных конструкций**, в которых обе части маркированы сослагательным наклонением, лишь **23 относятся к будущему и допускают гипотетическую интерпретацию. При этом описываемая ситуация представляется говорящему скорее фантастической, чем гипотетической:**

> (82) В качестве примера можно привести идею, выдвинутую американским учёным Г. Эвереттом, который пришёл к заключению, что многие проблемы современного естествознания получили бы неожиданное решение, если бы мы отказались от представления об уникальности Вселенной. [В. Н. Комаров. Тайны пространства и времени (1995-2000)]

Answer (score 1):

1) **Обычный вариант:** Если завтра будет хорошая погода, мы поедем на дачу. Это **потенциальное условие:** используется **изъявительное наклонение,** но ситуация имеет **гипотетический характер**, что связано с будущим временем. Наши действия зависят от погоды, мы не знаем, какой она будет.

2) **Если  завтра была бы хорошая погода, мы бы поехали на дачу.**

Это уже не потенциальное условие,  **а предположение** (пожелание, что-то вроде мечты): Вот если  завтра была бы хорошая погода, мы бы тогда поехали на дачу. Но мы пока не знаем, какая будет погода.

3) Еще один вариант (отредактированный): **Если бы на завтра был хороший прогноз погоды, мы бы поехали на дачу (а теперь останемся в городе).**

Пояснение: Прогноз уже дали  плохой, поэтому мы не поедем. Условие ирреальное (контрфактическое),  действие не состоится.

Comment: Согласен, ваш вариант более академический, но предлагаю улучшение: Если бы прогноз погоды на завтра был хороший/хорошим, мы бы поехали на дачу

Comment: Но мне кажется, вариант (а) возможен в разговорной речи.

Comment: Мне тоже стало казаться, что вариант (а) возможен, я исправила ответ.

Comment: Тут дело не в стиле, в предложениях а и  b семантика  разная.

Comment: @Sibylla: ¡olé! Вы подтвердили то что я думала! предполагала ситуацию: в бюро коллега спрашивает что мы будем делать завтра - ведь можно дать ответ "Если бы завтра была хорошая погода, мы бы поехали на дачу"?! но что мешает ему быть потенциальным условием? в будущем ведь все возможно?

Comment: Ну да,  два варианта a и  b вроде бы говорят об одном и том же. Но в одном случае просто указывается зависимость наших действий от погоды,  а  в другом  ВЫРАЖАЕТСЯ ЖЕЛАНИЕ поехать на дачу, если погода позволит. В будущем всё возможно, вы правы.

Comment: @Sibylla: я согласна с Вами, что СН может выражать желательность, но думала что это можно делать с конструкциями "мне бы ..." / "вот бы ..." / "хоть бы ...". это СПП условия и согласно книгам СН в СПП условия имеет значение реальное условие / гипотеза / контрфактивность; не нашла ничего про пожелание =(   я правильно понимаю: сам говорящий оценивает ситуации как возможные или ирреальные и (согласно его оценке о возможности случения(?) / ирреальности ситуации) решает какое наклонение надо использовать?

Comment: простите, пожалуйста, у меня еще один вопрос (он не по этой теме, но я здесь спрошу). Пример: "меня не удивит, если завтра выяснится, что мой муж изменяет мне". почему говорящий решает в пользу индикатива, а не говорит: "меня не удивило бы, если бы завтра выяснилось, что мой муж изменяет мне"?

Comment: Для выражения желательности действия можно использовать соответствующий глагол: Если завтра будет хорошая погода, мы хотели бы поехать на дачу. Но тоже самое можно выразить предложением: Если бы завтра была хорошая погода, мы бы поехали на дачу. Таким образом, примерно одно и то же содержание можно выразить разными наклонениями, это называется синтаксической синонимией. Но не следует смешивать понятия ирреального и гипотетического условия. Первое относится к прошлому, оно не будет реализовано, а второе относится к будущему, его реализация возможна.

Comment: По второму вопросу. Мне кажется, что используются оба варианта, например: Меня нисколько не удивило бы, если б среди страшной бури, свирепствовавшей вокруг нас, он вдруг очутился в моей каюте. Олега не удивило бы, если б в этом состоянии Коньшин и его принял бы за беса.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы точно знаете, что завтра будет плохая погода, и решили не ехать на дачу, тогда (a).
Если вы не знаете, какая завтра будет погодa, тогда - только (b).

Comment: Если кто-то о чём-то знает точно, то тогда конечно — на дачу, на канатчикову.

Answer (score 0):

Только вариант *b*:

по смыслу предложения почти одинаковы, но вариант *а* небезупречен стилистически - в нём два "бы"!

---

Да, увидела различия: в *а* (кроме недопустимых двух "бы", одно из которых заменяют на "б" или перестраивают предложение) подразумевается больший разброс вариантов поведения ("а если погода так себе, то поедем в гости", к примеру), а *b* говорит только о планах на дачу.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но почему "недопустимые два бы"? читаю везде что сослагательное наклонение в ирреальных предложениях оформляется как в главном так и в придаточном предложении (в художественной литературе нашла море таких примеров) + нигде никогда не читала что "одно из которых заменяют на "б"" :S

Comment: Galina говорит о правиле хорошего тона.

Comment: "3.3 Избыточное употребление частицы бы (б)
Частица бы (б) может быть использована при одном предикате дважды или более в разных местах клаузы. **C точки зрения норм литературного языка такие конструкции считаются ошибочными** (см., например, [Розенталь 1985: 293])". http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#33

Comment: @ Галина, речь идет о тех случаях, когда в одной клаузе в разных местах используется частица бы. В нашем примере две клаузы: главная и зависимая. В каждой по одной частицы бы.

Comment: Удвоение частицы типично для контекстов с союзами если (бы) и чтобы:

Answer (score 0):

Вариант а) Мы в сомнениях, ехать или не ехать. Пожалуй, поехали бы, если будет хорошая погода.

Вариант b) Мы хотим поехать на дачу, мы решили ехать, если только погода нам не помешает.

Comment: В варианте А — «если бы завтра была», а не «если будет».